# Why doesn't tcflush work for scanf?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I have this simple code to accept 3 characters,:

```
char a,b,c;
scanf("%c",&a);
scanf("%c",&b);
scanf("%c",&c);
printf("%c",a);
printf("%c",b);
printf("%c",c);
```

I understand why this will only accept 2 characters because the second scanf accepts the carriage return. However if if use `__fpurge(stdin);` between each scanf the code works as expected. But if I use `read(STDIN_FILENO,&a,1);` instead of scanf, it does not work. For `read()`, only `tcflush(STDIN_FILENO,TCIOFLUSH);` works but it fails with scanf. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Are you sure you called `__fpurge(STDIN_FILENO);` or was it `__fpurge(stdin);`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fpurge` empties the buffer at C level, which is the level at which `scanf` works.

`tcflush` does it at a lower level (system level), which is the level at which `read` works.

`scanf` uses `read` to fill its own buffer.

So in the first case: emptying the C-buffer with `scanf` works well, but does nothing at the system-level.

In the second case, emptying the system-buffer of course works with `read` but not with `scanf` because when you use `scanf`, data up at least up to the carriage return are already present in the C-buffer. The first `scanf`, reads plenty of data, place them into a buffer and then use that buffer to return you only one char. Then you `tcflush` which flushes the system-level buffer but does nothing to the C-buffer, so the following `scanf` is able to find the carriage return in it.

Comment: Can you please explain me how the C level buffer and system level buffer are connected by a simple example?

Comment: When you use an `fread` data are read from the C-buffer. If this one is empty then it is refilled from the system using `read`. When you `fwrite` data are written to the C-buffer. If this one is full, data are flushed to the system using `write`. Simply think about the way you manage the bucks in your pocket vs your bank account (pocket=c-buffer, bank=system; pocket full flush to bank, pocket empty, fill from bank)...